# FTP binary files to WS using MTOM/XOP

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm new to WSO2 ESB and would like some help on polling an FTP location for binary files and sending them to a web service endpoint (SOAP), making use of MTOM/XOP. Are there any examples out there?

Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Polling FTP location for binary files : 
Activate VFS transport in axis2.xml conf and define a VFS proxy, see https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/VFS+Transport

Send a message to a web service using MTOM : 
define a new endpoint in WSO2 ESB's console, choose "show advanced options" and in "Message Content" - "Optimize" choose "MTOM" : see sample 51 https://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136025